# RxJS / Angular Observables use 1 or multiple pipes?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Having the following (just a quick example):

```
observable.pipe(map( s => s.anything ))
          .pipe(filter(t => t > 5))
          .pipe(map( t => t+5))
          .subscribe( XXX )
```

Why should I use 1 pipe instead?

```
    observable.pipe(
                   map( s => s.anything ), filter(t => t > 5),map( t => t+5))
              .subscribe( XXX )
```

To me, the code is more nice and readable in the first case. But no idea if that affects the behaviour anyway.

Comment: why should you? first code works too doesn't it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use a single pipe for that purpose. Having multiple pipes will serve no purpose or benefit, as the usage of pipes is to combine RxJS functional operators into a single chain.

In order to make it more readable, you can do something like this, instead of having all the operators on 1 single line of code.

```
observable
  .pipe(
    map(s => s.anything ),
    filter(t => t > 5),
    map(t => t+5)
  ).subscribe(res => {
    // do the rest
});
```

The official Angular guide has a good summary on the usage of pipes and other operators. You may read up more about it over [here](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#operators). You should read up about pipeable operators over [here](https://reactive.how/rxjs/pipeable-operators) as well.