# How to, in 1 function, perform operations on 2 separate data collections in 1 function in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

How to perform operations on 2 separate data collections in 1 function in RxJS so that it returns observable -> as for now it returns Void ? This function is running inside Service of course, and finally I want to subscribe to it in my component.

I assume it requires refactoring, I'm still learning RxJS :)

My attempt (it does not work):
https://pastecode.io/s/m1g7a861

```
// use interface instead class for TS
export interface Task {
  goal_id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  priority: string;
  taskDate: string;
  id: string; // key collection
}

// Base Goal Model
export interface Goal {
  name: string;
  isMainGoal: boolean;
  details: string;
  category: string;
  lifeArea: string;
  creationDate: string;
  priority: string;
  endDate: Date;
  id: string;
}

class MyService {

    getTasksByCategory(category:string):Observable<any> {
        const daysFromThisWeek = this.getDaysFromThisWeek();
        return forkJoin({
          tasks: this.tasksS.tasksCollection(),
          goals: this.goalsS.goalsCollection(),
        })
        // !!! OPERATIONS ON GOALS !!! 
        .pipe(
          // filter goals with category from parameter
          map(({ tasks, goals }) => {
            return goals.filter((item:any) => item.category === category);
          }),
          // get ID's of found goals in the previous step
          map((goals:any) => {
            const goalsIDs = goals.map((item:any) => item.id);
            return goalsIDs;
          })
        )
        // !!! OPERATIONS ON TASKS !!!
        .pipe(
          // get IDs-matching-tasks
          map(({ tasks, goalsIDs }) => {
            let modArr = [] as any;
            goalsIDs.forEach((goalId:any) => {
              const forModArr = tasks.filter((task:any) => task.goal_id === goalId);
              modArr = modArr.concat(forModArr);
          })
          return modArr;
        }),
        map(tasksArr => {
          // get number of IDs-matching-tasks on each week day
          let finalTasks = [] as any;
          daysFromThisWeek.forEach((day:any) => {
              const forFinalTasks = tasksArr.filter((task:any) => task.taskDate === day);
              finalTasks = finalTasks.concat(forFinalTasks.length);
          })
          return finalTasks;
        })
        )
    }
    
    getDaysFromThisWeek() {
        let daysArr = [];
        for(let i=1; i<=7; i++) {
          daysArr.push(dayjs().startOf('week').add(i, "day").format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        }
        return daysArr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You are only returning the `goalsIDs` from the first `pipe`, so the input for the second `pipe` do not get the `tasks` emissions. Also as mentioned in the comments, having multiple `pipe`s to the same input observable isn't different from having a single `pipe` containing all operators.

Instead of performing the `map` opearations of `this.goalsS` observable after the `forkJoin`, perform it before. Then you could use the `goalIds` to filter the emission of `tasksS` observable.

Also I'm certain the filtering operations on tasks emissions could be done better, but I'll leave that to you.

Try the following

```js
getTasksByCategory(category: string): Observable<any> {
    const goalIds$ = this.goalsS.tasksCollection().pipe(
        map((goals) =>
            goals
                // filter goals with category from parameter
                .filter((goal: any) => goal.category === category)
                // get ID's of found goals in the previous step
                .map((goal: any) => goal.id)
        )
    );
    
    const tasks$ = this.tasksS.goalsCollection();
    const daysFromThisWeek = this.getDaysFromThisWeek();
    
    return forkJoin({
        goalIds: goalIds$,
        tasks: tasks$,
    }).pipe(
      // get IDs-matching-tasks
        map(({ tasks, goalIds }) => {
            let modArr = [] as any;
            goalsIDs.forEach((goalId:any) => {
                const forModArr = tasks.filter((task:any) => task.goal_id === goalId);
                modArr = modArr.concat(forModArr);
            })
            return modArr;
        }),
        map(tasksArr => {
            // get number of IDs-matching-tasks on each week day
            let finalTasks = [] as any;
            daysFromThisWeek.forEach((day:any) => {
                const forFinalTasks = tasksArr.filter((task:any) => task.taskDate === day);
                finalTasks = finalTasks.concat(forFinalTasks.length);
            });
            return finalTasks;
        })
    )
}
```

**Edit:** Added brief info about error in OP's code

Comment: I have a question -> is using 2 separate pipes as I did in my attempt valid/justifiable or you should never use 2 separate pipes ?

Comment: @PiotrDeja: Using 2 pipes is not wrong per-se, but doesn't add anything to the implementation. It's exactly the same as chaining the operators in a single pipe. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56018885/6513921

Answer (score 0):

Your first map is actually removing the `tasks` result. Instead, do something like this:

```
    .pipe(
      // filter goals with category from parameter
      map(({ tasks, goals }) => {
        return {
          tasks: tasks,
          goals: goals.filter((item:any) => item.category === category)
        };
      }),
      // get ID's of found goals in the previous step
      map(({ tasks, goals }) => {
        return {
          tasks: tasks,
          goals: goals.map((item:any) => item.id)
        };
      })
    )
```

You may even merge those

```
    .pipe(
      // filter goals with category from parameter
      map(({ tasks, goals }) => {
        return {
          tasks: tasks,
          goalsIDs: goals.filter((item:any) => item.category === category)
                      .map((item:any) => item.id)
        };
      })
    )
```

Comment: Notice that even if I appy your suggestion I get error in second pipe, map(({ tasks, goalsIDs }) => goalsIds is underlined in red

Comment: indeed, you in the map, I named the param "goals", not "goalsIDs". You can choose any, but they have to match. I updated my answer so you can use `map(({ tasks, goalsIDs })` after my map